# Software that turns color pdf to grayscale

Tags: pdf, document-converter, color

I'm looking for a software that turns several color PDF (around 1000) to grayscale or black & white. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Typically this is done when rasterizing. That is, when converting to an image or printing. Why is changing the actual PDF file itself to grayscale or b/w important for you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Our compagny would like to extract some informations from several handwrited documents, scanned and saved as PDF. We work with a start-up for that and they told us that they need to have grayscale or black and white PDF as an input, I couldn't say why, maybe they use some image recognizion algorithm for that and grayscale PDF are simplier to handle.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it from Adobe Reader using Adobe PDF printer.
Just go to Print (Ctrl+P) and select grayscale.

More info [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/using-pdf-printer.html).

[image: Gray Scale]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're in need of a solution to convert a large color PDFs to grayscale or black and white.

I recommend checking out SuperTool's [Color PDF to Black and White Converter](https://supertool.org/convert-color-pdfs-to-black-and-white/). This tool is designed to convert color PDFs to black and white or grayscale online, which could be a perfect fit for your needs.

You can adjust grayscale settings!

Comment: Note this appears to be a subscription-based service with daily, monthly, and yearly subscriptions available.